# how to remove child class from parent when I get sucess message in the childview controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, parent-child

I am presenting viewcontroller as chid viewcontroller.I Am presenting child viewcontroller in a popupview which is in parent class.plase find the below image to get clear idea.[image]

This the code i used to add present childvc in parent.

```
   [self.view addSubview:yopopup_view];
        yopopup_view.hidden=NO;

        yoviewcontroller = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yoviewcontroller"];
        CGRect contentFrame = yocontantview.frame;
        contentFrame.origin.y = yocontantview.frame.origin.y;
        contentFrame.size.height = yocontantview.frame.size.height;
        yocontantview.frame = contentFrame;
        yoviewcontroller.view.frame = yocontantview.bounds;
        
        [yocontantview addSubview:yoviewcontroller.view];
        [self addChildViewController:yoviewcontroller];
        [yoviewcontroller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Now i the childvc I have an api class when I get success message from backend I have remove child class from parentvc.

I am using the below code to remove child class from parent class.

```
[self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[_delegate closeyopopmethod:@"close"];
[self removeFromParentViewController];
```

When I use the code I am removing the child class but I have to remove popupview from the parent class superview.How to do that.

Thanks for quick responce.

Comment: You need to show the code how you are adding this Controller in your parent controller

Comment: @NiravD thanks for quick responce I will give the code

Comment: @NiravD please check the code.

Comment: What is `yocontantview` here ?

Comment: In the  popupview there is view where I am presenting childvc i.e yocontantview.

Comment: Where you implementing this delegate that you are calling `closeyopopmethod`, Are you implementing with the ViewController where you are showing this `yopopup_view` ?

Comment: yopopup_view this method is a protocoal.I am trying with protovoal but it is not working

Comment: Then show the protocol declaration code that you are trying where you are implementing it also have you set the delegate ?

Comment: @nirav  in child class . protocol closeyopop <NSObject>
-(void)closeyopopmethod:(NSString *)str;
end . after sucess  [_delegate closeyopopmethod:@"close"];  in parentvc . -(void)closeyopopmethod:(NSString *)str{

    if ([str isEqualToString:@"close"]) {
        yopopup_view.hidden=YES;
    }

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the `delegate` of `yoviewcontroller`, so set it to `self` when you initialized it.

```
yoviewcontroller = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yoviewcontroller"];
//Set the delegate to self
yoviewcontroller.delegate = self;
//Your other code
```

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu You need to set the `delegate` to `self ` where you showing this yoviewcontroller in `yopopup_view` the code that you have added in your question after I asked to show you

Comment: I am using this in viewwill appear 
  yoviewcontroller.delegate = self;

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu Not in viewWill appear you need to set it where you are adding this yoviewcontroller as child view Controller

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu you cannot ask anyone to forcefully upmark question

Answer (score 0):

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.childViewControllers lastObject];
[vc.view removeFromSuperview];
[vc removeFromParentViewController];
```

Comment: Hi vishal thanks for quick responce.When should i call this code and UIViewController *vc is which vc

Comment: if it works then mark it as accepted answer and up vote it else if you facing any error then let me know.

Comment: close button into child viewController?

Comment: the popup in parentvc how to close that

Comment: [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self removeFromParentViewController];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146485/discussion-between-vishal-kalola-and-satheeshkumar-naidu).